# redirect with js to another page, the same way like <a> html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

I have created an app with Dynamics 365, and I navigate from one page to another page

with the built in grids etc..

now I need to make a custom button to navigate to a page, so I try to use `document.location.href = 'url'`, but this make a whole other loading experience from opening it with the grids(the navbar gets also reloaded, and the record set option disappear)

so  I try to use the developer tool to see how Microsoft use to navigate from a grid row, to the form, and I see that there used a <a> html attribute to navigate,

so my question is how can I get the same behavior by using java script to redirect to a page, as pressing on a <a> link, or how can I make a dummy html <a> tag and click it with js?

here is the copied html, used by the grid to navigate

```
    <div role="presentation" style="max-width: max-content;"><a
            href="full url"
            class="classes" role="link"
            aria-label="text" tabindex="0"
            data-pa-landmark-active-element="true">
            <div class="classes" role="none"><span class="classes" role="presentation">text</span>
            </div>
        </a></div>
```

any help will be appreciated

I also try to use the other function form `document` object(`replace` etc ) but doesn't get me the same behavior like a <a> attribute, and i also try to use the `Xrm.Navigation` but nothing archive my needs

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamics 365, you can use the Xrm.Navigation object to navigate between pages.

Here is small example,

```js
function navigateToRecord(entityLogicalName, recordId, openInNewWindow) {
    var navOptions = {
        entityName: entityLogicalName,
        entityId: recordId,
        openInNewWindow: openInNewWindow
    };

    Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(navOptions);
}
```

now using this function will be something like this,

```js
<button type="button" onclick="navigateToRecord('account', '12345678-9ABC-DEF0-1234-567890ABCDEF', false)">Navigate to Account</button>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response, but by using the xrm.navigation, the record set option disappear,
but by navigating with a press on the link not. so basically what i need, is to be able to do in a java script function the same as clicking on a <a> attribute